# Nginx rewritte http to https but not /admin

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have client area which is https and works fine with this added to client.mydomain.com.conf :

```
server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name client.domain.com www.client.domain.com;

rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

All client.domain.com/* pages are https.

I also have one admin area which I'am sick to make it SSL 'optimized' by changing all admin area files content.

Link of admin area is client.mydomain.com/admin

What I need is to disable https redirect only to admin area client.mydomain.com/admin, while client.mydomain.com/* will be https redirected.

I tried with this bellow code but  I get error   ~duplicate location "/" in /home/nginx/conf/globals/proxy.conf:38 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed~

```
 server {
 listen 80;
 server_name example.com;
 location /admin {
   # handle admin area here;
   }
  location / {
  return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
 }
 }
 server {
  listen 443 ssl;
 server_name example.com;
 # ssl settings
 location /admin {
return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
 }
  location / {
 # handle all ssl pages here
   }
}
```

Here is 'client.mydomain.com.conf' file http://www.jsfiddle.net/LSyQq , it has no modifications, and here is conflicting proxy.conf http://www.jsfiddle.net/LJY3C

Answer (score 0):

Try this lines on the configuration is how I use to redirect my traffic

```
location ^~ /admin/ {
    rewrite ^ http://$http_host/$uri redirect;
  }
```

Let me know if it worked.

:)

Comment: I don't understand where to add it. Can you please edit the correct file in the correct link above ?